# API Platform: Normalizing a Mapped Superclass only includes properties from the superclass, not the child class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, api-platform.com

**EDIT:** Created a repo with a simple use case to replicate the problem, and created an issue in the API Platform issue queue at https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/1648.

I have a `SurveyData` mapped superclass, which has multiple child classes that implement it. For this question, `MonthlyData` is a child of the `SurveyData` superclass.

I have a `Submission` API resource that has a `OneToOne` relationship to a `SurveyData`.

I am trying to normalize the `SurveyData` child entity (in this case, a `MonthlyData` entity) inline into my Submission entity when I retrieve it. I've set the `normalizationContext` in my `Submission`'s `ApiResource` annotation, and set the `@Groups` annotations on the various properties I want to have inline.

It's mostly working, in that the properties of my `SurveyData` mapped superclass appear inline in my `Submission` entity, in addition to the `@id` and `@type` JSON-LD properties. **However, properties from the actual child entity (`MonthlyTotals`) do *not* appear.**

I can confirm that the object being passed into the normalizer is a fully populated `MonthlyTotals` object, but the output of the normalizer only contains the properties defined in the `SurveyData` mapped superclass.

I can confirm I am using the default core API platform JSON-LD normalizer.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Here is a `Submission` definition (minus 'use' statements and getters / setters for brevity:

```php
<?php
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *   normalizationContext={"groups"={"submission"}},
 *   denormalizationContext={"groups"={"submission"}},
 *   itemOperations={
 *     "get"={
 *       "method"="GET",
 *       "access_control"="is_granted('view', object)",
 *     },
 *     "put", "patch", "delete",
 *   },
 * )
 *
 * @ApiFilter(NumericFilter::class, properties={"patient.id"})
 * @ApiFilter(OrderFilter::class, properties={"created", "status", "patient.chartID"}, arguments={"orderParameterName"="order"})
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"status": "exact", "patient.chartID": "exact"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SubmissionRepository")
 * @DelphiAssert\SubmissionDataIsValid
 */
class Submission
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"submission"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Facility")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"submission"})
     */
    private $facility;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Patient", inversedBy="submissions")
     * @Groups({"submission"})
     */
    private $patient;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"submission"})
     */
    private $survey;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"submission"})
     */
    private $dateDetail;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\Type("\DateTimeInterface")
     * @Groups({"submission"})
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\Type("\DateTimeInterface")
     * @Groups({"submission"})
     */
    private $updated;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"submission"})
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"submission"})
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\SurveyData\SurveyData", inversedBy="submission", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true, fetch="EAGER")
     * @Groups({"submission"})
     */
    private $surveyData;
```

Here's SurveyData (same conditions):

```php
<?php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SurveyData\SurveyDataRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *   "SurveyData" = "App\Entity\SurveyData\SurveyData",
 *   "RPCSEducationProcessMeasures" = "App\Entity\SurveyData\RPCS\EducationProcessMeasures",
 *   "RPCSMonthlyTotals" = "App\Entity\SurveyData\RPCS\MonthlyTotals"
 * })
 */
class SurveyData
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups("submission")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Submission", mappedBy="surveyData", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $submission;
```

and here's MonthlyData:

```php
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *   normalizationContext={"groups"={"submission"}},
 *   denormalizationContext={"groups"={"submission"}}
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SurveyData\RPCS\MonthlyTotalsRepository")
 */
class MonthlyTotals extends SurveyData
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups("submission")
     */
    private $num_deliveries;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups("submission")
     */
    private $num_cesarean;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups("submission")
     */
    private $num_epidural_anesthesia;
```

Comment: Looks like serializers group problem. Can you show code of related entities?

Comment: Hi @shvv. I've added the entity definitions minus `use` statements and getters / setters for brevity. It seems reasonable to be a serializer groups issue, but I've worked through that documentation several times with no resolution.

Comment: @BrianV could you add the code for the serializer as well? I try to setup a test case and reproduce your issue.

Comment: floGalen: I've actually build a replication use case in a repo, and created a Github issue for it at https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/1648

Answer (score 0):

Might be `@Groups({"submission"})` v. `@Groups("submission")`.
Change all to `@Groups({"submission"})`.

It's hard to verify with current documentation, as it's now documented with PHP8 attributes. I've only used the YAML configuration, so not 100% sure.